# How to make background repeat in vertical direction using parallax

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have been looking to make background repeat in vertical direction but there is always some flickering..

I searched a lot on goggle and some book for reference but not able to find a proper reply
There are lot of proper reply for background repeat on horizontal direction

```
 -(void) update:(ccTime)delta
  { 
      CCSprite* sprite;
      CCARRAY_FOREACH([spriteBatch children], sprite)
      {

        NSNumber* factor = [speedFactors objectAtIndex:sprite.zOrder];

        CGPoint pos = sprite.position;
        pos.y -= scrollSpeed * [factor floatValue] * (delta * 50);


        if (pos.y < -screenSize.height)
        {
            pos.y += (screenSize.height * 2) - 2;
        }

         sprite.position = pos;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading new background each time? I strongly suspect flickering is caused by loading time in  texture. You can use threaded loading to avoid flickering.

[Here is once other question with something similar problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345556/cocos2d-continuously-scrolling-tile-based-game-strange-flash-only-in-device)

[Continuous-horizontal-scrolling-of-background-in-cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932027/continuous-scrolling-of-background-in-cocos2d/14932464#14932464): Refer my answer

Continuous vertical scroll:

```
 #define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
 #define MM_BG_SPEED_DUR       ( IS_IPAD ? (6.0f) : (2.0f) )

-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    [self initBackground];

    [self schedule: @selector(tick:)];
}

-(void)initBackground
{
   NSString *tex = @"BG/Background.png";//[self getThemeBG];

    mBG1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:tex];
    mBG1.position = ccp(s.width*0.5f,s.height*0.5f);
    [self addChild:mBG1 z:LAYER_BACKGROUND];

    mBG2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:tex];
    mBG2.position = ccp(s.width*0.5f,s.height*0.5f+mBG1.contentSize.Height);

    mBG2.flipY = true;
    [self addChild:mBG2 z:LAYER_BACKGROUND];

}


-(void)scrollBackground:(ccTime)dt
{
    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CGPoint pos1 = mBG1.position;
    CGPoint pos2 = mBG2.position;

    pos1.y -= MM_BG_SPEED_DUR;
    pos2.y -= MM_BG_SPEED_DUR;


    if(pos1.y <=-(s.height*0.5f) )
    {
        pos1.y = pos2.y + mBG2.contentSize.height;
    }

    if(pos2.y <=-(s.height*0.5f) )
    {
          pos2.y = pos1.y + mBG1.contentSize.height;
    }

    mBG1.position = pos1;
    mBG2.position = pos2;

}

-(void)tick:(ccTime)dt
{
    [self scrollBackground:dt];
}
```

Comment: Hi,thnx for quick reply...
My main concern is i want background to repeat top to to down in vertical direction...
I tried your link but background is repeating left to right
I change x and y but it did not work

Comment: Hi,thanks for such great reply ..
one problem through..while coming top to bottom the screen is shown blank every time...You can see the background empty ..

Comment: Hi..i am stuck at more point.Now,i run the code on device 3gs.The code seems to be not working correctly.

Comment: not working on 3GS...there is no device specific calls...checkout images are loaded..and size is proper. print(CGSize s width and height)

Comment: I am using 640x1136 image but it shows either space on both iphone 5 and 3gs.I tried increasing height like this if(pos1.y <=-((s.height*0.5f)+50) ).But it does not solve the problem

Comment: already supported iphone5? if yes then s.height = 1136 so no need to add +50. check Default-568h@2x.png is added or not. Its totally new question...so not good to put all in one..make new question!

Comment: ok,will post a new question.
Thanks for your help..Can u send me your skype id -it will be great help

Comment: ok added my answer in your new question..checkout..may be useful for you.